# Bad math (and code) while incrementing values

Tags: processing

Warning: I'm a total beginner. Very rookie mistakes ahead. The language used is Processing (Java).

I'm using functions to add numbers consecutively (i.e. 1+2+3+4+5+6 and so on) up to 10. I use the float "num" represents how high it should count up in this incremental manner, which is 10.

Next, I'm calculating factorials (1*2*3*4*5*6 and so on) up to 10.

My teacher gave the example in class for adding the numbers consecutively, which looks like:

```java
float Addition(float num) { 
float val1=1;
float val=0;
while (val1 <=num){
val=val+val1;
val1++; 
    }
return val;
  }
```

This adds to 55, as it should, since we're incrementing until we hit 10. Could someone please explain the concept of this for me? I'm working on a bit now that adds in increments of 4 (i.e. 0+4+8+12+16+20 and so on) up to 10, but my math is WAY is off; it should equal to 180, but instead equals 45:

```java
float Addition2(float num) { 
float val1=1;
float val=1;
while (val1 <=num){
val=val*val1;
val1=val1+val2+4;
    }
return val;
  }
```

I'm not looking for anyone to fix the math for me, but to explain the concept itself and how I would properly calculate this (if that makes sense).

Thanks in advance.

P.S.

As a bonus, here is my work on the factorial, again, also wrong. If someone could also explain the concept of this, that would be smashing:

```java
float Multiplication1(float num) { 
float val1=1;
float val=1;
while (val1 <=num){
val=val*val1;
val1=val1+2; 
    }
return val;
  }
```

Comment: it's  better to use for loops.
And which language are u using ? And why do u have those 2 pieces of code which are almost identical to each other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand code, try to take it line by line. It might help to add comments to it to understand. It might also help to use longer and more descriptive variable names. Let's try with the function that works:

```java
//this function adds up 1+2+...maxNumberToAdd
float addition(float maxNumberToAdd) { 

   //start at 1
   float currentNumberToAdd = 1;

   //keep track of your total sum
   float totalSoFar = 0;

   //loop 1,2,3...maxNumberToAdd
   while (currentNumberToAdd <= maxNumberToAdd){

      //add the current number to the total
      totalSoFar = totalSoFar + currentNumberToAdd;

      //go to the next number to add
      currentNumberToAdd++; 
   }

   //return the total
   return totalSoFar;
}
```

Now that you have that, you can think about modifying it to do your next task.

You say you want to start at `0` instead of `1`. Find the line of code responsible for starting at `1`. What happens if you change it to something else?

You say you want to add only every 4th number. Find the line of code responsible for going to the next number. What happens if you increase it by something other than `1`?

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the assistance. So I've changed the variable curentNumberToAdd to 4. Does this cause it to add 0+4=4, then 4+8=12, then 12+4=16... etc.? My intention is to add 0+4+8+12+16... etc., but it seems I'm adding 0+4+4+4+4... etc.

Comment: @AndrewK Why did you cahgne `currentNumberToAdd` to `4`? The `currentNumberToAdd` hold, well, the current number to add. You want that to increment by 4, not equal 4.